# need tool to : draw curve in browser (javascript) and get math function

Tags: javascript, function, math, draw, interpolation

I'm looking for the exact oposite of this tools : http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiJ4XjIiLCJjb2xvciI6IiMwMDAwMDAifSx7InR5cGUiOjEwMDB9XQ--

Here, we give a math function, it draw the function.

I need to draw some function and get the math function correspondent

EDIT :  If it's impossible, may be can get a resembling function ?

Comment: there is no such thing

Comment: @LorDex Why not? If it's impossible, may be can get a resembling function ?

Comment: how do you expect it to work? you draw whatever swirl you wish on the cartesian coordinates and it will magically come up with a function for you? Even if that's just a straight line (as you'd imagine y = ax + b) you do realise drawing it on the pixel-based screen will round the y to around-ish integer and it will never be accurate enough to get a formula? can you imagine human intelligence doing something like this? you think AI is THAT smarter?  are you serious?

Comment: A script can get all coordinates for each Natural point and deduce a function no?

Answer (score 0):

If you can restrict yourself to some specific class of functions, e.g. polynomials of degree no more than 10, then you have a bunch of parameters and you can use some optimization to tune these parameters to best match your input.

But your question doesn't specify such a class of functions, and the general form is not solvable: anything that you draw that might be a function (i.e. has at most one *y* coordinate for each *x* coordinate) can be explained by very different (and often *very* complicated) functions, which behave completely different outside the area of your drawing.

Comment: If you have a partial answer with polynomials of degree no more than 10, I got it^^

Comment: @Matrix: To fit a polynomial of given degree to a set of points, you build a matrix where row *i* column *j* has element `x_i^(j-1)`, i.e. the *x* coordinate of the *i*-th data point, raised to the power of *j* minus one. This matrix has as many rows as there are data points, and one column more than the degree of the resulting polynomial. Then use [least squares approximation](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/613804/35416) to determine the coefficients of your polynomial.